# Пишу игру runner platformer на Unity, не получается добавлять платформы рандомно по горизонтали

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, что бы платформы  добавлялись рандомно не всегда по центру, а например со сдвигом влево и вправо по x(-1,1)

```
void Spawn() {
    GameObject go = Instantiate(TilesArray[RandonPrefab()]) as GameObject;
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * SpawnZ; 
    SpawnZ += lenprefabs;
    objs.Add(go);
}
```

Comment: `go.transform.position += new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), 0,0);`

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

При создании объекта(метод Instantiate()) можно прописать несколько параметров: сам объект, позицию, поворот и родителя. Так вот вам надо менять значение позиции. Подробней [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)
Вам просто нужно записывать рандомное значение, [вот дока](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое) исправил по докам) все заработало как и хотел!

Comment: @user383829 ну так поставьте правильный ответ :^

Answer (score 0):

void Spawn(int prefabindx = -1)
    {

```
    GameObject go;

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f), 0, SpawnZ);
    if (prefabindx == -1)
        go = Instantiate(TilesArray[RandonPrefab()], position, Quaternion.identity);
    else
        go = Instantiate(TilesArray[prefabindx], Vector3.forward*SpawnZ, Quaternion.identity);
}
```